# Dell XPS 13 9350 WIFI and BT issues

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, broadcom, xps

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my XPS 13 9350.  It does have the Broadcom wifi/bt adapter.

My wifi issue is the computer will not connect to my 5GHZ network. Every time I try it just fails to connect and asks me for the password even though it's correct(I checked multiple times).  I can connect to my 2.4ghz but not the 5ghz.  I just get the spinner and then a prompt for the password

My BT issue is I have always have to repair my BT mouse when the computer restarts.

I previously had a XPS 13 9343 and I had no issues like this.  I was able to connect to my 5ghz network and using Bluetooth manager as a trusted device my mouse always reconnected at a reboot and that also had a broadcom chip

I know there are some issues with Broadcom adapters but my 9343 had one and I did not have this issue at all.  Is it just because the 9350 has a newer broadcom chip so it's not fully supported? Maybe I have a bad card? (I did just get this machine as a replacement)

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0023]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Added output as requested

Comment: Maybe try 16.10 in live mode on a USB? If that works, look into updating the driver: http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: @JoakimKoed Same behavior on the live CD.  Connects to 2.4ghz fine, won't connect to 5ghz.  I have also tried installing bcmwl-kernel-source and that completely broke wifi